# strong convergence sufficient conditions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Would it be true that $\mu_n \to \mu$ strongly if $\int f\mathrm{d}\mu_{n}\to \int f\mathrm{d}\mu$ for every uniformly continuous function? Assume the space is $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and has the usual topology. I am reading some paper and it seems to use this as a fact. I cannot see the difference between assuming $\mu_n \Rightarrow \mu$ and this condition mentioned above (uniformly continuous function). $\Rightarrow$ (weak convergence) obviously does not imply strong convergence, and so I am confused.
The paper which I am talking about is "Weak convergence of a sequence of Markov Chains" - AF Karr, it is not a HW problem.

Comment: By strong convergence I guess you mean $\mu_n(A)\to \mu(A)$ for each measurable $A$. If we take $\mu_n:=\delta_{n^{-1}}$ and $\mu:=\delta_0$, then $\int f\mathrm d\mu_n\to \int f\mathrm d\mu$ for each continuous $f$. But we don't have the strong convergence.

Comment: Do you have a link to the paper? I didn't manage to find it.

Comment: here it is   http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00539859
its on page 44 (of the journal or same as page 4 of paper ) extreme bottom (6) Theorem ...... i can send you the paper in mail or message...it is "Weak Convergence of a Sequence of Markov Chains"
Alan F. Karr

Comment: I would be thankful (my mail address in on my web page).

Comment: I got the point now, what I was saying was wrong.He used the fact that continuous functions with compact support (bounded continuous functions) are dense in $L^{1}$ to show that $\mu = \mu K$ via sequence of measures which converges weakly to $\mu$. 
$\mu(g) - \mu K(g) = \mu(g)-\mu^{n}(g)+\mu^{n}(g)-\mu K(g) =\mu(g)-\mu^{n}(g)+\mu^{n}K^{n}(g)-\mu K(g) $, where $\mu^{n}K^{n} = \mu^{n}$
continuing
$\mu(g)-\mu^{n}(g)+\mu^{n}K^{n}(g)-\mu K(g)= \mu(g)-\mu^{n}(g)+\mu^{n}K^{n}(g)-\mu^{n}K(g)+\mu^{n}K(g)-\mu K(g)  $, now if $K^{n}\to K$ pointwise and $\mu^{n}\Rightarrow \mu$ then the above goes to 0.

Comment: I am a beginner in advanced probability , so may be this question is very straightforward but it is bugging me. (Is?) weak convergence the same as convergence in probability if we assume that the sample space is $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and the random variable for the sequence is just the identity mapping to $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, in other words the only difference between the two arises because weak convergence does not involve the underlying sample space into its definition?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\int f\mathrm d\mu_n\to\int f\mathrm d\mu$ for each uniformly continuous function does not imply strong convergence, as $\mu_n:=\delta_{\frac 1n}$ and $\mu=\delta_0$ shows.  This only gives weak convergence. And it is not what the author uses, as the OP noticed.

Strong convergence is equivalent to $\lim_n\int f\mathrm d\mu_n=\int f\mathrm d\mu$ for each $f\in L^\infty$, which is restrictive. Weak convergence is weaker than convergence in probability.